# ¿Cómo disparar un event-listener con una función (virtualmente)?

Tags: javascript, websocket

hola estoy intentando hacer un web-socket para usar con [p5js.org](http://p5js.org), pero la única cosa que me funciona es esto:https://socketservice.herokuapp.com/ la sintaxis es la siguiente:

```
SocketService.init( 'my-awesome-room', socket => {
    socket.on( 'my-event', data => console.log( data ) )

    htmlbutton.addEventListener("click",socket.emit( 'my-event', { msg: "hello from button" } ))

    socket.on( 'room-joined', room => {
        console.log( `socket joined ${ room }` )

        socket.emit( 'my-event', { msg: `hello from ${ window.location }` } )
    } )
} )
```

y me gustaría usar algo mas simple:

```
function Socket(room,callback){
  this.room=room;
  this.recived=callback;
  this.send=function(obj){

  }
}
```

juntando los dos códigos... cuando recibo un mensaje llamo al callback y ningún problema, la cosa es cuando quiero enviar un mensaje desde cualquier parte de mi código debería llamar Socket.send(object) y esto disparar un evento dentro del socketservice como el del botón y ejecutar el socket.emit:?

```
button.addEventListener("click",callback)
```

entonces como disparo un evento virtual?

o se os ocurre algo mejor?

gracias:)

Comment: Hello, we are at Stackoverflow in Spanish please edit your question by translating it so it can be accepted and answered ;)

Comment: gracias, ya lo he traducido

Comment: intenta con button.click()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No se si he entendido bien tu problema. Esta es mi propuesta para manejar fácilmente eventos por `socket` en toda la `app` sin tener que reinstanciar todo de nuevo.

```
addEventListener("load", async () => {

    await SocketManager.init('test-room');
    const htmlButton = document.getElementById('test');
    htmlButton.addEventListener("click", () => SocketManager.send('test message'))

});


class SocketManager {
    static socket;
    static debug = true;
    static room;
    static async init(room) {

        SocketManager.room = room;
        return new Promise((resolve) => {
            if (SocketManager.socket) {
                return resolve();
            }
            SocketService.init(room, socket => {
                SocketManager.socket = socket;
                if (SocketManager.debug) {
                    socket.on('room-joined', room => console.log(`socket connected ${room}`));
                }
                return resolve();
            });

        });
    }

    static send(msg, key = `${SocketManager.room}_defaultEvent`) {
        if (!SocketManager.socket) {
            throw new Error('Socket is not connected. Please use init function before send.');
        }
        SocketManager.socket.emit(key, msg)
    }
}
```

---

Y la parte de la vista para hacer pruebas solo tengo esto.

```
<body>
    <button id="test">test </button>

    <script src="https://socketservice.herokuapp.com/SocketService.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
```

Básicamente el funcionamiento es el siguiente. Necesitas utilizar al menos una vez en la `app` el método `init` para conectarte a la `room` deseada.
Después de esto puedes usar tantos send como necesites.

Te recomiendo separar la clase `SocketManager` en otro fichero para tener distribuido mejor el código.

Espero que te sirva.

Salu2.

Comment: muchas gracias, es justo lo que queria